# Restkit mapping for array with no keypath

Tags: rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

How can I create an object mapping for a JSON response like this, which is just an array of integers:

```
 [
 565195,
 565309,
 565261,
 565515,
 565292,
 565281,
 566346,
 566347,
 575241,
 597230,
 597231,
 597227,
 597228,
 597229,
 597232,
 575248
 ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to perform a `nil` keypath mapping. Check the 'Mapping Values without Key Paths' section [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping).

Comment: And how can I define mappings for composing JSON request with the same structure? Because inverseMapping does not work here.

Comment: @ebi, could you share the code for this mapping please?