# RESTKit - post a large array of objects to server

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

How can I post an array of objects to my server with RESTKit?

I have a custom object called `Contact` which have some properties like `name`, `phone` etc. I would like to send an array of these `Contact` objects to the server.
The method I know for this is `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure`, but what object I put here? If I put `Contact` - how will it know it is an array? and if I put `NSArray`, how will it know it is a `Contact`?

My `Contact` object header file is:

```
@interface Contact : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger order;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;

@end
```

my response mapping is:

```
RKObjectMapping *personMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class]];
    [personMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                   @"username": @"name",
                                   @"firstname" : @"firstName",
                                   @"lastname" : @"lastName",
                  }];
```

my response descriptor is:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *personResponseDescriptorForArrayOfPhones =
[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:personMapping
                                             method:RKRequestMethodANY
                                        pathPattern:@"getUsersInfoByPhones"
                                            keyPath:nil
                                        statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

my request mapping is:

```
RKObjectMapping *personRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping ]; 
    [personRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                         @"name": @"username",
                         @"firstName" : @"firstName",
                         @"lastName" : @"lastName",
                         @"phone" : @"usernames"
              }];
```

my request descriptor is:

```
RKRequestDescriptor *personRequestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:personRequestMapping
                                                                                     objectClass:[Contact class]
                                                                                     rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodAny];
```

Does this implementation looks good?

Also, this array I want to send to the server could be very big, around 200-1000 objects. Is that possible with RESTKit?

**Update**: Actually, I would prefer to send an array of strings (which would be phone numbers), and get from the server the `Contact` objects I have. How can I set RESTKit to post the array of strings and to expect a response of an array of `Contact` objects?

The json I need to send looks like this:

```
{
    "usernames":["11","22"]
}
```

the json I expect to get is:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : "53e23a54e811310000955f70",
    "profileUpdatesCounter" : 3,
    "lastname" : "SMITH",
    "firstname" : "BOB",
    "username" : "11"
  }
]
```

Comment: Possibility depends on context - device, data availability, memory availability. Try. If you have a problem, show the code you used and the server log of what it received. Can you do the same thing from a test system (browser plugin or similar)?

Comment: what would be the object to put in the postObject: method? Would it be a NSArray?

Comment: could you please explain more about how to exactly send the array?

Comment: You just pass an array. You need to have the associated request descriptors configured. Update the question to show your source data, mappings and desired JSON, together with what you actually get out. (RestKit looks into the array to see what objects are there to know what to do)

Comment: This does not work for me. My server expects the to get an array of usernames in the body of the request. I think that the postObject: method does not do it exactly. Do you know how can I do it? Or what should I tell me server to expect?

Comment: So you're currently sending too much data (you don't show the JSON you want and the JSON you get...). Try using a nil key path mapping / searching https://www.google.com/search?q=restkit+post+array+of+strings.

Comment: I've updated the question with the JSON I get/send. I'm already using nil in the key path. I've already searched the web, but didn't find an explanation

Comment: nil key path mapping, not response descriptor.

Comment: what do you mean? where do I specify this?

Comment: See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004327/restkit-mapping-for-array-with-no-keypath