# RESTKit - post an array of objects

Tags: ios, post, restkit-0.20

How can I post an array of objects to my server with RESTKit?

I have a custom object called `Contact` which have some properties like `name`, `phone` etc. I would like to send an array of these `Contact` objects to the server.
The method I know for this is `postObject:path:parameters:success:failure`, but what object I put here? If I put `Contact` - how will it know it is an array? and if I put `NSArray`, how will it know it is a `Contact`?

Comment: I haven't used RESTKit, but, have you tried the two approaches that you've mentioned? Let it figure out what the object is, if it can't it will at-least hint you about what it needs in form of an Exception

Comment: Have you already tried something like: NSDictionary *parameters = @{"ContactKey":@[contact1,contact2]} and then use that dictionary for posting objects?

Comment: Please update your existing question instead of asking a new copy of the same thing.

Comment: @Wain I wasn't sure if it's the same question, since the first one was about the **ability** of RESTKit to send a **large** array, and this was about **how** to send an array. But I've updated the [former question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228098/restkit-post-a-large-array-of-objects-to-server) anyway.

Comment: @razor28 I have tried your suggestion, but it didn't work with RESTKit. The error I get is : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot merge parameters with array of object representations serialized with a nil root key path.'`